# JSON into SQL results - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have JSON definitions in a SQL table, from there I am trying to parse it into a SQL Server view or a table (anything would be helpful).

LookupJSON table has a single column called definition_JSON and an example of one value looks like this:

```
{"__type":"userTask","name":"Grade Report","id":4,"directApprove":false,"emailNotification":{"body":"<p>Hi, your Form was successfully submitted! <\/p>","emailType":2,"subject":"Form Submitted"},"lock":false,"submitBool":true, "submitBtn":"Submit"}
```

I just need to get the name, userTask and id as results.

When we tried the following query it didn't like that nested query, it is expecting JSON.

```
Select * 
From parseJSON (select top 1 * from LookupJSON)
```

We are using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Title say 2012, tags say 2008, and content say 2012 R2 (that doesn't even exists). Are you sure you are not using postdbcle sql?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: synchronized everything to "SQL Server 2012" - assuming that's what he's actually using :-)

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: @ZoharPeled how is this a duplicate? Please link the "original"?

Comment: You need to get values from a json string. Link to the original is on the top of your question, bolded in yellow.

Comment: @ZoharPeled that post doesn't answer my question which is why I asked it. I have to put a JSON value into the parseJSON selector, I am looking for a way to insert the JSON value from another table which doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is this `parseJson`? Sql server only have json methods since 2016 version...

Comment: @ZoharPeled SQL 2016 has NATIVE json parsers (ways to read it), with older versions you have to get creative. That is why I need community help...

Comment: Well the linked question have some answers on how to parse json in older versions, but you claim it's not a dupe, so I try to understand why you think so...